# AddFileDependency alternative in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am migrating the following to asp.net core from asp.net mvc.

`context.Response.AddFileDependency(filePath);
context.Response.Cache.SetLastModifiedFromFileDependencies();`

Is there an alternative to this or a way to implement the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the changes in the response header with and without this piece of code and found that this adds a header `Last-Modified` with a value of last modified datetime of the provided file.

Hence, did the following in the asp.net core version.

```
var fileInfo = _fileProvider.GetFileInfo(filePath);
context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().LastModified = fileInfo.LastModified;
```